# Loading assets in Flutter for desktop (Windows)

Tags: windows, flutter, sqlite, assets, sqflite

I am trying to load SQLite DB in Flutter for Windows (it's working on Android), but I receive an exception, my code is :

```
// Copy from asset
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "mydb.sqlite"));
List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
```

I receive this exception :

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception:
> Unable to load asset: assets\mydb.sqlite
> #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7) 
> #1      DatabaseHelper._initDatabase (package:myapp/database_helper.dart:54:11) 
> #2      DatabaseHelper.database (package:myapp/database_helper.dart:29:17) 
> #3      DatabaseHelper.queryAllRows (package:myapp/database_helper.dart:80:19) 
> #4      _MyHomePageState._query (package:myapp/main.dart:193:15)

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error. I was able to fix it by changing

```dart
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "mydb.sqlite"));
```

to

```
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/mydb.sqlite");
```

The parameter passed to the load function should exactly represent the path provided in the `pubspec.yaml` file (seems like the `join` function twists the `/`to a `\` on windows)

```yaml
assets:
    - assets/mydb.sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

Assets paths in flutter windows also use unix separator `/` not `\`. Don't use `path.join()` to construct asset path and instead use `yourStringList.join('/')`